# Get culture name from cultureCode

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a built in method in .NET to convert a culture code into a user-friendly name? E.g:

- *en-GB* - English - United Kingdom
- *et-EE* - Estonian - Estonia
- *pa-IN* - Punjabi – India
- *fo-FO* - Faroese – Faroe Islands

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`CultureInfo` has a property called `DisplayName`

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");
var displayName = culture.DisplayName;
```

`DisplayName` gives you a **localized** version of the name.
There is also a `EnglishName` property. ;)

Comment: Which call does he use to get the CultureInfo from the code? Is that just the static GetCultureInfo?

Comment: @Rup, you can get the current culture via Sytem.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture

Comment: @Bokka nobody asked for the **current** culture.

Comment: Seems that I've misunderstood @Rup's question. Didn't mean to demean your answer, gave you +

Comment: No problem, I didn't take it as you've tried to demean my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
string displayName;

CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fo-FO");

displayName = cultureInfo.DisplayName;
```

EDIT:

Removed `if (culture != null)`.

Comment: I don't think the return value of `GetCultureInfo` can be `null` because it throws a `CultureNotFoundException/ArgumentException` (.NET 4/ .NET 3.5) on a invalid culture name.